# CSS dropdown navigation cut-off

Tags: html, css, browser

I'm running into a problem with the footer navigation on a site which has a drop-"up" menu that is cut off by another div.  I've set overflow: visible for all applicable divs in the footer & set z-indexes for correct content stacking, but to no avail.

I've started to run out of potential solutions.  Can anyone help me resolve this?  I would greatly appreciate it.

Here are links to the HTML & CSS:

HTML: jid (dot) eresources (dot) ws/default.html 
CSS: jid (dot) eresources (dot) ws/css/styles.css

Sorry - not enough points to post a [screenshot](http://www.focusontheclouds.com/files/jid-nav-issue.png)...

This is my first post here, so please let me know if I can provide any additional details to make this more helpful.  Thanks!

Comment: Not an answer, but might it be a good idea to remove the class from the `a` tag in the li? It currently has the same class as its parent.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need the tag on both for when we add the script to make the dropdown navigation work for an older browser - IE6 I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have your `#wrapftr` set to hide any overflow with `overflow:hidden`. So since the menu is within the `#wrapftr` div, and it overflows the div's boundaries, it's being hidden.

If you change,

```
#wrapftr {
...
    overflow: hidden;
...
}
```

to

```
#wrapftr {
...
    overflow: visible;
...
}
```

It should work fine, since then the menu can then display any bits that go outside of the `#wrapftr` boundaries.

Comment: That works great. Thanks a bunch! 

That's what I get for defining the same property in two different places.

Do I need to do anything to mark this as closed?